# Clicking a row to go to another path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my HAML file:

```
    %table.table-base.table-striped.table-hover{:id => "work-list-table"}
      %thead
        %tr
          %th{'no-sort' => 'true'}= t('worklist.work_list')
          %th{'no-sort' => 'true'}= t('worklist.number_of_work_items')
      %tbody
        -for x in [1,2,3]
          %tr{:id => x,href: duplicate_claims_work_lists_path, :style => "cursor:pointer"}
            %td
              %ul.custom-ul
                %li
                  %h4
                    = "hello"
            %td
              %ul.custom-ul
                %h4
                  = "3"
```

This creates 3 rows with columns "hello" and "3". I was under the assumption I would be able to click any of the 3 rows to path to duplicate_claims_work_lists_path, but it stays on the page, and it is not pathing at all. Here is some similar code that when clicked on the row correctly paths:

```
%table.table-base.table-striped.table-hover{:id => "remittance-table"}
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:type => 'payer'}= t('payers.payer')
      %th.data-type-number{'sort-type' => 'totalPayments'}= t('remittances.total_remittance')

  %tbody
    - @remittances.each do |remittance|
      %tr{:id => remittance.id,href: edit_remittance_path(remittance), :style => "cursor:pointer"}
        %td= remittance.payer.name
        -remit = remittance.total_payments.to_i >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg"
```

Any idea why I can't get the first code example to path anywhere when I click the row? `duplicate_claims_work_lists_path' works because I have a menu sub-bar take me there.

Comment: There is no need to use a hash to set a non dynamic id, use `%table.table-base.table-striped.table-hover#work-list-table`, also you don't need `=` for non dynamic content, you can remove them (with the quotation mark) for `%h4 = "hello"` and `%h4 = "3"`, finally you should avoid mixing the old hash style `{:key => value}` and the new hash style `{key: value}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an `href` attribute on a `<tr>` element, that is not how links work. Links are made using the `<a>` element.
The easiest way to make links in Rails is to use the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper :

```
%tbody
  - for x in [1,2,3]
    %tr{id: x}
      %td
        = link_to duplicate_claims_work_lists_path
```

To be honest, I don't really know why you second example works.